# topojson.py issue converting Point objects from geopandas created geojson

Tags: python, gis, topojson, geopandas

I'm trying to convert information from a geopandas df into a topojson with python, using topojson.py. In this case, all of the geometries it the gpd df are shapely Points. geo_df.head() looks like this:

```
    geometry
0   POINT (61.39313083609281 34.73857657446109)
1   POINT (61.68715178647459 34.62839735680247)
2   POINT (61.02182917574118 34.6419671306646)
3   POINT (60.9017205031241 32.07261235932085)
4   POINT (61.0167260004123 32.15043416326984)
```

I can convert to geojson using:

```
gpd_df.to_file("points.json", driver="GeoJSON")
```

But when I try to convert that geojson to topojson like so:

```
topojson("points.json", "pointstopo.json", quantization=1e6, simplify=0.0001)
```

I get the following error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/topojson/mytypes.py in 
Point(self, point)
     35             self.polygon(coordinate);
     36     def Point(self,point):
---> 37         self.point(point['coordinates'])
     38     def Polygon(self,polygon):
     39         self.polygon(polygon['coordinates'])
TypeError: point() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When I look at the geojson, point coordinates are given as two values:

```
"type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", 
"coordinates": [ 62.269649605592754, 32.429278041035452 ] } },
```

It seems like topojson.py is expecting a shapely Point (or something like it), which has only one argument for a set of coordinates, rather than the geojson I have.

Am I correct in this understanding of the topojson.py error? If so, any thoughts on a workaround? Am I using topojson.py correctly?

I understand that I'm not getting any benefit from the topojson format if I'm just encoding Point geometries, but I plan to use it in other cases with both points and polys.

Comment: The geojson is correct in any case: see example on home page of http://geojson.org/

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Though I was really asking if I was correct in my understanding of the topojson.py error. Have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Yes, I know. But even when you load the geojson as json->dict, accessing the coordinates should give a single object (a list of two elements). So I don't directly know where the error would be coming from. You could report it to topojson.py

Comment: Thanks -- reported it!